# Como Utilizar uma Classe dentro de outra Classe CSS

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Tenho uma tabela, e quero que as linhas intercalem cores
da maneira abaixo funciona perfeitamente

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr{height: 20px !important;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr td{padding-left : 5px;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:hover {background-color: #E4E1C9 !important;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ECFFEE;}   
</style>
```

o problema é que as cores ali estabelecidas, devem vir de outra classe list_cor_sim e list_cor_nao, vi uma forma de fazer isto utilizando Less/Sass/cs-modules porém não posso utilizá-los pois o projeto que estou modificando não utiliza, e não posso adiciona - los

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564916/nesting-css-classes

exemplo de como "gostaria" que funcionasse

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cor_hover{background-color: #E4E1C9;}
    .list_cor_sim{background-color: #ECFFEE;}
    .list_cor_nao{background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr{height: 20px !important;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr td{padding-left : 5px;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:hover {.cor_hover() !important;}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(even) {.list_cor_nao();}
    .tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(odd) {.list_cor_sim();}   
</style>
```

com javascript, nao estou conseguindo adicionar o mouseouver e mouseout (addEventListener nao esta funcionando)

```
function zebrar() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabela_parametros_gerais");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

        var cor;
        if(i % 2 === 0){
            cor = "list_cor_sim";
        }else{
            cor = "list_cor_nao";
        }
        row.classList.add(cor);
    }
}
```

Comment: `.list_cor_sim {background: red}` e `.list_cor_nao {background: blue}`... sua dúvida não ficou clara

Comment: atualmente já existe as classes list_cor_nao e list_cor_sim, e preciso utilizá-las para saber qual cor adicionar, entende?

Comment: `.tabela_parametros_gerais tr.list_cor_nao:nth-child(even) { }` já tentou?

Comment: tentei agora e não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira

```
function zebrar() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabela_parametros_gerais");
    for (let i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        let cor = i % 2 === 0 ? 'list_cor_sim' : 'list_cor_nao';
        row.classList.add(cor);
        row.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            this.className = 'list_cor_hover';
        });
        row.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            this.className = cor;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Browser e muito menos o HTML não vai processar isso para você por segurança. o modo mais fácil seria utilizando uma view-engine, se não um pré-processador. Aparentemente você não pode usá-los, para fazer essa alteração então deve usar javascript.

```
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(even)')
        .forEach(el => el.classList.add('list-cor-nao'))
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabela_parametros_gerais tr:nth-child(odd)')
        .forEach(el => el.classList.add('list-cor-sim'))
</script>
```

Comment: certo, tinha conseguido com javascript, porem nao consegui adicionar o mousehover e mouseout

Comment: Também da com um loop dentro do container, mas pra funcionar só pode conter os targets

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo inserir as classes no carregamento da página do lado do servidor.

em php ficaria assim:

```
$result = mysqli_query($CONN,$sql);
$linhas = myslqi_num_rows($result);
for($x=0;$x<$linhas;$x++){
   $campo = mysqli_result($result,$x,'campo');
   $class_linha = $x % 2?'linha_cor_sim':'linha_cor_nao';
   echo "<tr><td class=$class_linha>$campo</td></tr>";
}
```